# Why does the program return different value when I order the list differently?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to learn how to analyze large data better, and I wanted to make a program where by inputting a CSV of keywords you can look for the occurrence of each in a second data csv. I setup this code as an example, I created a list of keywords but when I switch the order of the first word the occurrence it returns is incorrect. For example when "matlab" is first it returns 97 which is right. but when I put either of the other words first it returns 0. It doesn't make sense to me because in my head it is iterating over the data set csv for every single word in the list, and checking. Could I get some help and clarification.

I've tried putting a print statement after first for loop and it is iterating over each word, confused as to why its not executing the later parts correctly.

```
import csv 
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
from array import array
import csv
keywords = read_csv("Book1.csv")
with open('ss.csv','r') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
    list=["matlab","souren","deez"]
    Attended=0
    no_show=0
    Registered=0
    word = 'matlab'
    nuts=[]


    for x in list:
        for row in reader:
        
            if x in row['one']:
                Registered=Registered+1
                

    print(Registered)
```

EDIT:

```
import csv 

import pandas as pd
from array import array
import csv
keywords = pd.read_csv("Book2.csv")
biomedical = keywords['Biomedical'].tolist()
Registered=0
counts = dict.fromkeys(biomedical, 0)


with open('ss.csv','r') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
    lines=list(reader)
  
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)  
df = pd.read_csv('ss.csv')


ss=df.stack().value_counts()
            
print(ss)


##print(ss)
#for x in biomedical:
#    print(x)
```

````
<br>

solidworks, microsoft office, lua","Python, MATLAB, C++, HTML, CSS, Javascript, C,

<br>

SOLIDWORKS, Microsoft Office, LUA","I would like to further my experience in SOLIDWORKS,

<br>

my extra personal skills, and develop my coding skills.",Female,,Yes,No,Yes,No,"Mississauga, Canada",No,No,Terese Kattar,Student was approved to submit Fall 2022 application,Yes,,,10/31/2022,11/14/2022,,,,,,,
Mechanical Engineering,2022 - Fall,Application Accepted (Final Status),11/14/2022,BaoAnh Le,yes,10/31/2022,Lauren,Sena,Shirley,Dacanay,,,Melissa,tkattar@ryerson.ca,(647) 518-3977,,Mechanical Engineering,,,Mississauga,L5M 6N3,Female,Canadian,In Canada,N/A,false,Active,Uploaded,2.7,No,,No,,No,No,"Accommodation and food services, Administrative and support, waste management and remediation services, Construction, Financial services and insurance, Health care and social assistance, Information and cultural industries, Management of companies and enterprises, Manufacturing, Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction, Other services (except public administration), Professional, scientific and technical services, Public administration, Real estate and rental and leasing, Retail Trade, Transportation and warehousing, Wholesale trade, Educational Services",Yes,Yes,"expert in c and javascript.

<br>

can proficiently use matlab.

<br>

skillful in microsoft word, office and excel.

<br>

knows the basic of vue and vuetify.

<br>

expert in html and css.

<br>

expert in google docs, slides, sheets.

<br>

skillful in cad software, such as: fusion 360 and solidworks..

<br>```
````

Comment: `reader` is a "one-shot" stream of lines: once you go through it, next times it will *not* rewind to the start and give the same lines back. Two solutions: 1) you can cache the reader's contents, e.g., `lines = list(reader)`, which will put the entire content of the file to a list that you can iterate over however many times you like. 2) you can swap the order of for loops you have: see how would that help?

Comment: also you have overridden the good old `list`, which will cause issues if you wanted to use the "real" `list`; it's better to not shadow the built-in names.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I see so you are saying instead of using with open, save the data csv into a list first, then iterate over that list.

Comment: not instead of using open actually, you need to open the file after all. it is exactly as you show in the edited version. As for the current issue: you're accumulating only 1 `Registered` variable for *all* of the possible keywords, and also you're only looking at the "one" field: are those desirable? I assume you wanted to keep separate sums for each keyword, but not sure about only looking at the "one" column, that's for you to say.

Comment: @MustafaAydın so yes I realized that that's the problem, I don't know how to tackle is precise, I was thinking of appending it to an array system somehow maybe like one dimension for each word. still I'm not sure how I would implement it, that what do you suggest? I want to look through each row for each keyword and then move on to the next row and check for all the keywords again. and the data would have multiple occurrences for each row. maybe have it run a function not sure.

Comment: you can have another for loop to look for every field in a given row instead of only the "one" field. So, for col in row:` under `for row in lines:` and then have your check as `if x in row[col]`. please print(row), print(col) and print(row[col]) in some places to see what they correspond to. To address separate counters per keyword issue, you can have a dictionary of 0s to begin with where the keys are the keywords, e.g., `counts = dict.fromkeys(biomedical, 0)` is a way of initalizing such a dictionary. Then if the `x in row[col]` condition is satisfied, you'd increment x's value in counts.

Comment: noting that `x in row[col]` is looking for a *partial* match, e.g., `"matlab" in "dramatlabian"` is True. if you need an exact match in a cell, you'd replace `in` with `==`.

Comment: lastly, as this is tagged pandas, you can say goodbye to all loops! pandas has `value_counts` functionality in it, which you can use as: `df.stack().value_counts()[biomedical]` where we first flatten the entire dataframe (the CSV's representation in pandas) with `stack` and then count the frequency of each unique value with `value_counts` and lastly select the words of interest out of that frequency table using `[biomedical]` selector.

Comment: Okay so I tried the dictionary method, but it will only increment it once, pretty sure I have the incrementation part wrong. As for pandas, it does not give a variety of errors, one of them being "self is not defined" and if I define that and put in the variables for stack() it gives the error of something about the axis, could you put a short code snippet to help me out.

Comment: "None of [Index(['vhdl', 'matlab'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]" this is the exact error.

Comment: I see why its grouping the rows in a weird way in value_counts. ill add the csv if you care to run it and see I also updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mustafa's first suggestion, I did it using for loops however there is a much better way of doing it with pandas which I didn't spend time to figure out.

```
import csv 
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
from array import array
import csv
keywords = read_csv("input1.csv")
biomedical = keywords['Biomedical'].tolist()
Registered=0
counts = dict.fromkeys(biomedical, 0)


with open('ss2.csv','r') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
    lines=list(reader)
  

for x in biomedical:
    for row in lines:
        for col in row:
            if x in row[col]:
                #print(row,col,row[col])
                counts[x]+=1
                #print(x)
                
with open('hh.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in counts.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,counts[key]))
                

print(counts)
#for x in biomedical:
#    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exhausting the *reader* upon completion of your inner *for* loop. You can simplify this as follows:

```
import csv

with open('ss.csv', newline='') as csvfile: 
    Registered=0

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        if (one := row.get('one')) is not None:
            Registered += any(x in one for x in ("matlab", "souren", "deez"))
                
    print(Registered)
```

Comment: I dont quite understand the code, so it is importing the CSV, then in each row if the row heading is "one" then I don't understand the rest.

Comment: also it gives a syntax error   if (one := row.get('one')) is not None:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @codingnoob That's because you're using an out-of-date version of Python (pre-3.8). Update your Python and run the code against your file and see what happens. Either that or modify the code so as not to use the assignment expression

Comment: you were right that works now but now I'm trying to get it to have more than one counter any suggestions?